# Is smoking allowed?

Tags: translation

Could I wave a pack of smokes and ask "daijoubu?" to see if I'm allowed to smoke?

Comment: Maybe I'm biased as a non-smoker, but this seems obnoxious regardless of language. Particularly the "waving" the pack. It says to me you're assuming it's okay before you ask.

Comment: Could I wave a pack of smokes and ask "OK?" to see if I'm allowed to smoke?

Comment: I don't smoke either. I'm just learning Japanese & trying to figure out how certain words can be used based on their translation. I've heard "daijoubu" used inquisitively to ask if something was good & just wanted to know if usage in this scenario was correct in order for me to have a better understanding of it's usage. I know "genki" means something similar to good/okay but I think is more specifically targeted to a person's well being. I think I came to the wrong place learn more about the Japanese language.

Comment: It sounded like you were asking a culture question. Explaining the purpose of the question in more detail would help people understand it better.

Comment: I can understand the "waving a pack" thing when you are a tourist with poor pronunciation, the pack would make the context understandable much faster by the clerk. Even to this day, I have many experiences of having to say the same thing many times to be understood by a clerk. I would only think this "waving" to be somewhat ok in izakayas and places that are not too formal. Personally, I don't think the person is assuming it to be ok to smoke unless they are already getting one of the cigarettes out before asking. (sounds like a cultural/personal question indeed)

Comment: I’m voting to close this question because it's more of a cultural question thus off-topic. Waving a pack and making some voice, you'll look like you're asking something about smoke. We could focus on the usage of 大丈夫 but in order for that the question needs much more focus.

Answer (score 2):

**Hello Malu, i assumed that you're a foreigner office worker, who traveled to Japan to work for the 1st time. In case you wanted to ask permission from others to smoke, you can say these sentences (depends on context/ situations you're in)**

**1/Sumimasen, kokode tabaco wo sutte moiidesuka ? ("Excuse me, can i smoke here ?" )**

This is the polite version, when you're speaking with your boss or a stranger you met for the 1st time.

**2/Kokode sutte moii ? ("Can i smoke here? ")**

Short and casual version, if you wanted to speak with a JP friend/ colleague at your working place.

**Hope my answer will help you have motivation to learn Japanese and having fun while working/ living in Japan.**

Answer (score 1):

To give a full breakdown:

[大丈夫]{daijoubu} cannot be "okay" in the sense of "permissible", but only in the sense of unharmed, in good condition, feeling all right, etc. It overlaps to some extent with [元気]{genki}, but the latter is more affirmative - actually in high spirits, more than just "okay" - and forms different idioms (大丈夫 might for example be used colloquially as something like "I'm fine, you don't need to bother helping me with this", or "don't worry, everything will be okay", depending on context, whereas [お]{o}[元気]{genki}[です]{desu}[か]{ka} is a common expression roughly equivalent to "How are you?").

The plainest form of "okay" in the sense of "permissible" is [いい]{ii} (also written 良い), literally "good". However, you will definitely not get away with just saying that by itself and gesturing - that will just be rude, and call attention to your status as a foreigner and lack of effort in trying to communicate properly. Even formalizing this like いいですか will not realistically get you anywhere; you'll want to actually explain what you're asking about.

The standard idiom here is to use the te-form of a verb (roughly comparable to forming a participle or gerundive in English using the `-ing` suffix) plus [も]{mo} + いい. The literal meaning works out something along the lines of "also okay in the case of whatever-ing", i.e., "will the situation still be good if I do whatever?".

In the current example, we use the verb [吸]{su}[う]{u} - in the primary sense, to breathe or to suck up/in, but also to smoke (cigarettes). We can be more explicit by saying what we propose to 吸う - in this case, [タバコ]{tabako} (a loanword from the English "tobacco", normally used specifically for cigarettes). Thus, fully elaborated,「タバコ[を]{o}[す]{su}[って]{tte}もいいですか？」. In Daniel's example, we also add [すみません]{sumimasen} (a set expression for "excuse me"; the hyper-literal meaning is something more like "the matter is not settled" or "I still owe you something") and [ここ]{koko}[で]{de} meaning "here".

Comment: But 吸っても大丈夫ですか is also fine tho… (nuance is only slightly different)